# Multiset intersection-like operation in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, guava

Given two multisets, for example, the first one:

```
Green
Green
Blue
Yellow
Yellow
Yellow
Cyan
Cyan
```

And the second one:

```
Green
Yellow
Yellow
Magenta
Black
Black
```

I need to get their intersection so that the result would look like:

```
Green
Green
Green
Yellow
Yellow
Yellow
Yellow
Yellow
```

What is the efficient way to achieve this in Java?
(Any link to a library or function would be appreciated.)

Comment: `intersection(Multiset<E> multiset1, Multiset<?> multiset2)`, details [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html) for Guava Multiset

Comment: Are you sure that your desired result is really an intersection? Intersection of regular sets is defined to be a set of such elements that are contained in both sets. But there are not 3 Greens and not 5 Yellows both in set A and B. In a multiset intersection, I would expect that the number of repeated elements would be the minumum of the number of those elements in the input sets.

Comment: @arin1405 Thanks for pointing to this. However this function gives minimum out of two values (so the result is 1 Green and 2 Yellows), and I need the sum.

Comment: @Gandalv Not really sure should it be called "intersection", you're right. Please suggest a more appropriate term so I can fix the title.

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev i can't think of one term. You just need all elements from two sets that are contained in their intersection. And that's actually how I would implement it. So better title would be probably something like Intersection-like operation on multisets...

Comment: Mathematically speaking, the intersection of two multisets is well-defined (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Multiplicity_function). Guava's `Multisets.intersection` method is based on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want the [*sum*](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#sum(com.google.common.collect.Multiset,%20com.google.common.collect.Multiset)) of the multisets, filtered to include only the elements that appear at least once in their intersection. Here's one way you could get the result you're looking for in Guava:

```
ImmutableMultiset<String> first = ImmutableMultiset.of(
    "Green", "Green",
    "Blue",
    "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow",
    "Cyan", "Cyan");
ImmutableMultiset<String> second = ImmutableMultiset.of(
    "Green",
    "Yellow", "Yellow",
    "Magenta",
    "Black", "Black");

Multiset<String> result = Multisets.filter(
    Multisets.sum(first, second),
    Predicates.in(Multisets.intersection(first, second)));

System.out.println(result);  // [Green x 3, Yellow x 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Guava Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), which has similar API to normal Java `Set`, including retain operations you may be interested in.

Also please be advised that questions asking to recommend a tool/library are typically considered offtopic on SO because the answers are really subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Given your Multiset is a descendant of Set, you can retainAll from one to the other and the other way around, and then combine both subsets like this:

```
multiset1.retainAll(multiset2);
multiset2.retainAll(multiset1);
multiset1.addAll(multiset2);
```

If I understool your question correctly you will end up with what you want in multiset1, although you may need to sort it.
The cardinality should be correct doing it that way.